# Why I cannot disconnect internet

Tags: networkmanager

When I run the command

```
nmcli dev disconnect iface eth0
```

to disconnect  the internet connection, it is disconnected and and after a few sconds the KDE network icon changes to 
[image]
and internet is connected (because I'm posting this question).

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 64bit

Comment: What is in `/etc/network/interfaces` related to eth0?

Comment: `auto lo`

`iface lo inet loopback` nothing else

Comment: See in the connection settings if it is not configured to connect automatically.